# submit a disabled input in a form could not get value

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit

The form is like below;

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" data-clear-btn="true">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" data-clear-btn="true">
    <input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="textinput-disabled" id="textinput-disabled" placeholder="Text input" value="<?php echo $info;?>">
</form>
```

$info = "type1"; and the $info works fine in the form.

but In the sendmail.php

```
$name=$_GET['name'];
$type=$_GET['textinput-disabled'];
$phone=$_GET['phone'];
```

I get the name and phone, but I can't get the value in the textinput-disabled.
What's the problem here.

Comment: Most (all?) browsers do not send disabled fields on form submit

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Disabled fields are not submitted. You can make it readonly or hidden, to get value when submitted.

```
<input readonly type="text" name="textinput-disabled" id="textinput-disabled" placeholder="Text input" value="<?php echo $info;?>">
```

Answer (score 6):

Thats expected behaviour.

Instead use

```
<input readonly type="text"...
```

Or if you must use disabled for some reason, add a hidden field:

```
<input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="textinput-disabled" id="textinput-disabled" placeholder="Text input" value="<?php echo $info;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $info;?>">

$name=$_GET['name'];
$type=$_GET['hidden'];
$phone=$_GET['phone'];
```

Comment: hidden is also a good choice.but in my situation guess it not a good  one.BTW. thanks for your attention.

Comment: @robinclark007 which is why i suggested `readonly` as the most appropriate solution....

Answer (score 0):

As disabled `input` cannot be submitted in form so you can use `readonly="readonly"`, so use below :

```
<input readonly="readonly" type="text" 
       name="textinput-disabled" id="textinput-disabled" 
       placeholder="Text input" value="<?php echo $info;?>">
```

For more information on **[readonly](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with a checkbox. 
Since the readonly value doesn't change a checkbox so that it cant be clicked, I still had to use the disable option. 
So I just added a hidden field with the desired variable name right below the checkbox:

```
<input type = 'checkbox' value = '1' name = 'EnableD_".$NR."' ";if($noti["ACTIVE"]==1)echo " checked "; echo " disabled >

<input type = 'hidden' value = '1' name = 'Enable_".$NR."' ";if($noti["ACTIVE"]==1)echo " checked "; echo " >
```